# Moving Google Form into Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

My daughter has a survey in Google Form and wants to put the form as an appendix in her Google Doc.  Is there any way to produce a "Word" version of the form--with the questions and check boxes as one sees online--and put them in Docs?

Comment: You could use a screen capture program to get an image.  Jing is a free one I have used. SnagIt is, I believe 50.00 US and will scroll down a page for a long form.  Both are by the same company and I have no affiliation outside having used them for many years.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend printing a copy of the form as a pdf so that it can be easily attached.  When you generate a printable copy of the form it makes a number of changes to the format to assist in printing.  For example, it will make a list of all options in a drop down.  This is more useful than a screen shot, which wouldn't include all of the content of the form.

First, you may need to download a print to pdf utility to allow you to save a pdf from your print dialog.  On Windows I prefer using CutePDF: http://www.cutepdf.com/

To generate the printable copy of the form make sure your form is open and click the vertical '...' button on the top right.  Then select 'Print.'  In the destination dialog change the destination to Save as PDF/Print to PDF.  It then asks you for a location to save it to and there you have it, a pdf of your form.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Forms, you can click in the three dots next to send and click Print

[image: Google Forms to docx]

Then we're redirected to the following screen

[image: Print]

It's in portuguese in my case. In the highlighted dropbox I defined want the file to be saved as PDF (from the portuguese "Guardar como PDF").

Once you have the .pdf you can just copy-paste mostly everything.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by printing it as a OneNote file. In Google Forms, you can click in the three dots next to send and click Print.

[image]

Save it as a OneNote file, then you open it and you will find copyable pictures like the figures in the response section in Google Forms.

[image]

When you copy them to a Word document they look pretty cool.

[image]

Comment: sorry, my answer looks a little messed up.